# Reading from application.properties scheduled rate in minute

Tags: spring

I am scheduling tasks with Spring, and the following code works well.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${rateInMillisecond}")
    public void update()
    {
        System.out.println(this.message);
    }
}
```

Now, if I config rate in minute, for example having

```
rateInMinute=30
```

in my `application.properties`, is there a way to use this property to set scheduling rate?
30 minutes is 1,800,000 (i.e. 30 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds. So the question is how to set `fixedRate` or `fixedRateString` based on calculation based on a property?

Comment: Isn't the RHS of `fixedRateString` a Spring Expression? If so, you should be able to say something like `= ${rateInMinute * 60 * 1000}`.

Comment: I tried `=" ${rateInMinute * 60000}"` and it didn't work. It got runtime error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'update': Could not resolve placeholder 'rateInMinute * 60000' in value "${rateInMinute * 60000}"`

Comment: Ah, shoot. You could try putting the math op outside of the braces, but it does look like a dead end. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you Noah for your comment. With `=" ${rateInMinute} * 60000"`, I get a slightly different error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'update': Invalid fixedRateString value "30 * 60000" - cannot parse into long`

Comment: Hmm. What about `= "#{${rateInMinute} * 60000}"`? I am seeing syntax like that at [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Noah, this solves it:

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{${rateInMinute} * 60000}")
```